# ¿Como obtener la posición de un elemento de un listview sin tener que darle click al elemento?

Tags: java, android

Quiero lanzar una notificación cuando un elemento de un listview llegue a una determinada posición, (0,1,2,3,4,5) etc, ejemplo que cuando llegue a la posición 3, lanzar la notificación. Que propiedad de los listview debo utilizar.

El lenguaje es java sobre el sistema operativo Android.

Ejemplo:

Estoy llenando un listview con los siguientes elementos:

posición 0: manzana, posición 1: pera, posición 2: uva, posición 3: naranja, posición 4: ciruela, posición 5, melocotón.

Dichos elementos se van eliminando del listado de acuerdo a su utilización, quiero que cuando ciruela llegue a la posiciona 2 enviar una notificación al usuario que diga "Ciruela esta actualmente en la posición 2 de un vistazo a la aplicación".

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje de programación? ¿Y qué significa exactamente "*que llegue a una posición*"? ¿El usuario está seleccionando un elemento? ¿O cuando se agregue un ítem en la posición 3? ¿Qué posición es la que te interesa obtener? ¿O la idea es seleccionar por el contenido?

Answer (score 0):

Buscando algo, ojo no le he probado si funciona

Como que un `ListView` puede mostrar más de un elemento a la pantalla, con el siguiente código se puede detectar los ítems visibles.

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        //firstVisibleItem el primer ítem de la lista visible
        //totalItemCount el total de ítems visibles  
    }
});


private boolean listIsAtTop()   {
    if(listView.getChildCount() == 0) return true;
    return listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
}
```

Para determinar si un valor está dentro del rango:

```
 public static boolean isBetweenAndEqual( int value,int start, int end) {
     return end > start ? value >= start && value <= end : value >= end && value <= start;
}
```

en tu caso para saber si la posición 3 está visible:

`isBetweenAndEqual(3,firstVisibleItem,firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount);`

Answer (score -1):

Si estás actualizando el listview con un `notifyDataChanged()` en el adaptador, en el método `getView()` (`onBindViewHolder()` si es un RecyclerView) recibes la posición como argumento. Simplemente tendrías que comprobar si es la que te interesa y mandar un evento o una llamada a la actividad.

Comment: Ok, si estoy usando `notifyDataChanged()`, me diste mas o menos una idea de como hacerlo si. Gracias!